# Doubt in chapter $9$ of Rudin( functions of several variables)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

My doubt over here is in page no $212$ of Rudin chapter 9-section (Differentiation)

We are defining the differentiation as :

$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+r(h)$ where $r(h)$ is the remainder so that $lim_{h \to o}r(h)/h=0$.

Then it states that :

> we are defining the derivative of $f$ at $x$ as a linear function that takes $h$ to $f'(x)h$.

I am not sure of why this statement is true as we are defining $f(x+h)-f(x)$ as the linear function that takes $h$ to $f'(x)h$ and what does this statement even mean(Why do we even have to do this?).I also have a problem in the way he is trying to link things with linear transformation.Can someone just sum it up.

Edit 1:2. Derivative of a linear transformation. If $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ is linear transformation, then $f (a + hy) =f(a) + hf(y)$ and the difference quotient $\frac{f(a + h) -f(a)}{h}$ is equal to f(y) for every $ h \ne 0$. In this case,
$f’(a; y)$ always exists and is given by
$f’(a; y) =f(y)$
for every $a$ in S and every $y$ in $R”$. In other words, the derivative of a linear transformation
with respect to y is equal to the value of the function at y.

This a paragraph from Apostol.I was just wondering whether this has a link with the way Rudin has defined things?What does the derrivative of a linear transformation mean?

Comment: What do you mean by *remainder of the function*?

Comment: No: $f(x+h)-f(x)$ is not in general a linear function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, the derivative of $f$ at $x$ (if it exists) is the unique linear function $L$ such that
$$
\lim_{|h|\to0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-L(h)|}{|h|}=0.
$$
If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, this reduces to $L$ being multiplication by the number $f'(x)$.

Some examples:

- In single variable calculus, to estimate the change in a function near a fixed $x$, we multiply the change in $x$ by $f'(x)$, i.e.
  $$
  f(x+h)-f(x)\approx f'(x)h=L(h),
  $$
  and think of this as depending on $h$.
- In in multivariable calculus, we have the Jacobian matrix $L=\left(\partial f_i/\partial x_j\right)_{ij}$.
- If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ we have the gradient $L(h)=\nabla f\cdot h$ for $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I dont understand why $L$ in higher dimension is not the multiplication by the number $f'(x)$ and how is this linked with gradient ?

Comment: So doesn't this boil down to the fact that the derrivative of a  function at x is not $f'(x)$ but $f'(x)x$?

Comment: The derivative isn’t a number:  it is a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstood the definition of the *differential*  of a function: it is the best linear approximation $l(h)$  of $f(x+h)-f(x)$ in a very precise sense, based on asymptotic analysis:
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+l(h)+o(\Vert h\Vert).$$

Comment: What is asymptotic analysis?How is a linear transformation linked with gradient?

Comment: Asymptotic analysis is about comparison of functions, with  the big O and little o notations, and equivalence of functions. Gradient is the vector notation for the differential of a function of several variables. The differential is not a number, except for a function of a single variable